# Cannot load auto-complete library

Tags: auto-complete-mode

I have installed auto-complete in the /Users/angeldelcastillo/.emacs.d/auto-complete directory following the instruction on the website, using install.el. The process finishes all right, but when I open Emacs I get this:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading       >`/Users/angeldelcastillo/.emacs':
>
> File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, popup
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
>   the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

I have modified ~/.emacs as follows:

```
    ;; autocomplete-mode
    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete")
    (require 'auto-complete-config.el)
    (ac-config-default)
```

I'm using Emacs 24.4 on OSX. I have this installed on a Ubuntu machine and there it works. So the trouble is with the popup directory, which I don't know where to find. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not need `.el` in `(require 'auto-complete-config.el)`; it should be `(require 'auto-complete-config)`. If that still doesn't solve the problem, restart emacs with `emacs --debug-init` and update the question with the error log.

Comment: It sounds like you're just missing the `popup` dependency.  You can keep installing dependencies by hand, but` it's better to use the package manager.

Comment: Finally used the melpa package manager. Alright now.